# Add a linux network bridge device between untagged VLAN1 and tagged VLAN100

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge

I want to add a network bridge between a tagged vlan device and the untagged vlan1.
That doesn't work as I expected it to work. First I want to show the configuration of
the network as it is at the moment. After that I explain what I want to do and how I did it (but not working).

This is the network:

```
  ____________    ______________
 |   IP-Cam   |  |   WinPC      |
 |            |  | autoIP e.g   |
 | 172.16.0.3 |  | 169.254.1.23 |
 | 0.0.0.0    |  | 255.255.0.0  |
 |____________|  |______________|  
    | V1U         | V1U
 ___|_____________|_        _______________
|                   | V100U|               |
|      Switch       |------| Service Port  |
|                   |      | 192.168.25.x  |
|___________________|      |_______________|
                | V1U, V100T
                | (eth0)
            ------------------------------------
           | Linux Box                          |
           | eth0 Service (V100T): 192.168.25.99|
           | eth0 autoip: 169.254.31.23         |
            ------------------------------------
```

I have a system with a network switch, an IP-camera, a linux boxs, a service port (switch) and a windows PC for other things.
The switch is configured that there is a tagged VLAN100 for the service port. 
The VLAN100 has a tag on the linux box port to provide a separet interface with a special service address.
The switch removes and adds this tag on the V100U port so that the service port (pc) doesn't need
any knowledge of VLANs.
The WinPC has like the linux box an auto ip address and provides a special service.

This configuration on the linux box looks like this.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
   # get an auto ip by avahi e.g. 169.254.31.23
   up avahi-autoipd -D --force-bind eth0
   # add route for the IP-Cam
   post-up ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0

# service port
auto vlan100
iface vlan100 inet static
   vlan_raw_device eth0
   address 192.168.25.99
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

That configuartion works. So from the linux box I can access the IP-Cam and the WinPC.
The serivce port does also it's job and the linux box can be accessd over the vlan100 device on 192.168.25.99.

The system requirements changed and I need another configuration. First of all, I can't change the switch settings because
it is a pre programmed embedded switch.
What I need know, is that the Service Port (V100U) on the switch, behaves like the port for the IP-Cam/Win-PC. What means that
want to bridge the V1U with the V100T device. So a device connected to the service port can access all V1U ports without knowledge over VLANs.
The Service Port is not usead anymore as a service port :).

So I changed the configuration as follows and thought that there is nothing special:

```
# V1U network
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual


# V100T network
auto vlan100
iface vlan100 inet manual
   vlan_raw_device eth0  

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
   bridge_ports eth0 vlan100
   # get an auto ip by avahi e.g. 169.254.31.23
   up avahi-autoipd -D --force-bind br0
   # add route for the IP-Cam
   post-up ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 dev br0
```

After changing the settings to this. The network behaves wired. So sometimes I can ping the IP-Cam from the linux box and sometimes not.
Also a device connected to the service port can sometimes ping the linux box and sometimes not. Pinging the IP-Cam from the service port
never works. So I guess I add a loop or something else.
Any ideas how I can get the system running?

Comment: I update the configuration using the right route command. That didn't help, as you expected. I logged the data with tcpdump and checked them with wireshar. It seems, that the arp entries for the IPs are lost after some pings and only after a arp a new arp request the pings continues.
What is unclear to me is, if a linux bridge bridges all data including all VLANs or if it realy only bridges the V1U and the V100T.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the VLAN100 device. The eth0 device gets V1 untagged and V100 tagged devices. So what would happen if I add the eth0 device, how does the bridge know, that it only shouold use the V1 untagged data and not also the V100. I would expect, that a bridge bridges everything.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find was this thread:

https://bridge.linux-foundation.narkive.com/KYSQbc1f/bridging-untagged-and-tagged-vlans#post5

which says basically, it doesn't work, you have to coerce ebtables into making it work, which everybody agreed to, but the untested sample didn't work.  And there was a Linux-2.4 patch that did what we want but apparently it didn't get accepted.

I wound up using a vlan-capable switch to tag out VLAN 1 and just went with eth0.1 as a bridge member.

That thread is old enough that I hoped there was a better answer but did not find one.